Visual Studio 2022 not showing correct CSS in IDE
I made some changes to the CSS, and when I debug in the IDE, the old CSS keeps showing up. When I publish it to the web server, the changes I made are shown. Verified the files have all the changes. I did clear cache in Visual Studio, but it is still showing the old CSS.
I tested the CSS on web server and it works correctly.
